# Когда передвигаю карту, то убегает инфовиндов

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, geocoding

Ccылка на страницу: http://rzeszowskie-nieruchomosci.pl/oferta/1813

Геокодер правильно ставит точку, но когда начинаю двигать картой, то смещаеться инфовиндов

```
    var map = {
        address: '',
        content: '',
        cords: null,
        geocoder: null,
        mapOptions: null,
        infowindow: null,
        object: null
    };

    function initialize() {
        map.address = '{{ entity.city }}, {{ entity.street }} {{ entity.apartment }}';
        map.content = '<div id="info-content">';
        map.content += '<div class="address">{{ entity.street }} {{ entity.apartment }}</div>';
        map.content += '<div class="text">Lokalizacja nieruchomości<br />powyższej oferty.</div>';
        map.content += '<div class="arrow"></div>';
        map.content += '</div>';

        map.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        map.mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: map.cords,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            scaleControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map.object = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), map.mapOptions);

        map.geocoder.geocode(
                {'address': map.address},
                function (results, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        map.cords = results[0].geometry.location;

                        map.object.setCenter(map.cords);
                        map.object.panBy(-60, 0);

                        map.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: map.content,
                            position: map.cords,
                            center: map.cords
                        });

                        map.infowindow.open(map.object);

                        google.maps.event.addListener(map.infowindow, 'domready', function () {
                            var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');
                            var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();
                            iwBackground.children().css({'display': 'none'});
                            iwOuter.parent().parent().css({left: '101px'});
                            iwOuter.parent().parent().css({top: '-37px'});
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: От каких индивидов карта убегает?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в стилях, которые написал старый верстальщик